# SQL запрос по двум таблицам с условием в каждой из них

Tags: sql, sql-server

Задание стоит такое:

Нужно в таблице групп найти группы выполняющие двум условиям

группа факультета теоретической физике

группа с максимальной численностью превышающей 20 человек

[image: Таблица групп]
[image: Таблица факультетов]

Для выполнения задания нужно обратиться к таблице Факультеты.

Не понятно как всё это выполнить. На C# я бы это сделал запросто, а тут непонятно.

Comment: Может быть стоит использовать [Join](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-2017) ?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, а как им воспользоваться?

Comment: Нажать на приведенную ссылку, прочитать про него, посмотреть примеры,. подставить в примеры свои имена таблиц и колонок.

Comment: @Mike, но мне нужен, в сущности, только один код факультет, который мне нужно вычленить из таблицы Факультеты

Comment: А это не имеет значения. join точно такой же. он по id и в where указываете условие на имя факультета. Можно конечно воспользоваться конструкцией `IN(подзапрос)`, но join надо первым делом учиться писать, потому что это базовая концепция sql, без которой дальше никуда и в ряде случаев join быстрее подзапросов

Comment: @Mike, Вот что у меня получилось, хотя оно и не работает select Группы.Код_факультета, Номер_группы, Максимальное_количество_человек, Куратор_группы, 
Название_факультета
from Группы join Факультеты on Факультеты.Код_факультета=Группы.Код_факультета
where Название_факультета= '%теоретическая физика%' and 
Максимальное_количество_человек > 20

Comment: Ну оно наверное работает, только ничего не выдает, потому что у вас нет факультета с наименованием `%теоретическая физика%`. Не путайте оператор `=` который проверяет на точное равенство с оператором `like` который находит вхождения и у которого символ % это маска любых символов

Answer (score 0):

Совместными с комментаторами усилиями написал запрос

```
select Название_факультета, Номер_группы, Максимальное_количество_человек, 
Куратор_группы
from Группы join Факультеты on Факультеты.Код_факультета=Группы.Код_факультета
where 
Максимальное_количество_человек > 20 and
Название_факультета like '%теоретической физики%'
```

Как отмечал @Mike, здесь важно чтобы была именно `like`, а не `=`